# Web video does not play in any browser on Windows 10 system wide

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, youtube, video-playback

I turned on my computer today and I found that I couldn't play a YouTube video. The page would load and everything looked normal, but the video was in a constantly-buffering state, paused on the first frame of the video. I could scan the timeline of the video, but the video would not play and in some random cases where it did play, there would be no sound and the buffering circle would appear over the video.

I troubleshooted this extensively:

- Checked internet quality, very fast, no interruptions.
- Cleared cache and cookies, tried Chrome incognito mode.
- Disabled my ad-blocker and any other extension that could be causing an issue.
- Tried using Firefox, Opera, and Brave browser. Same issue on all browsers.
- Pulled out my Apple laptop and my phone, played a video just fine on both systems.
- Tried other video sites like Twitch and Vimeo. Same issue.
- Turned my computer on and off again several times, even installed a Windows update.
- Checked graphics driver for updates.
- Installed Malwarebytes and scanned for viruses (it found nothing)
- (Here's the kicker) Opened a local .mp4 video file in VLC, ran as expected. But when I opened that same local video file in chrome, I experienced the same playback issue.

This really seems to be a strange Windows issue. I've never had it before and I'm out of troubleshooting ideas aside from rolling back to a previous system backup. Nothing out of the ordinary was installed or changed with my rig recently (aside from moving it to a new place). Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this. I have an external audio interface that is connected via USB. It was certainly working, I heard system audio and audio from some music software that I use just fine, but something went wonky for some reason and changing the USB port that it was connected to fixed the issue with videos. I have no idea why this was, I hadn't moved the USB port since the last boot-up so I guess Windows just decided it didn't like it overnight or something.